# How to identify if a a regular expression is null or not inside a script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I'm tracking badwords and if it exists in a comment when user in currently typing it is replacing with ***. But I wanna to identify if it replaces or not when typing. If so display a div tag. I have done upto tracking part and also displaying div tag but I cannot understand how to identify whether it replaces the word or not. Please help me to change my code

```
       <script>
        function fbws(text){
        var getWord = document.getElementById(text);
        var regex1 = /(dam|hell)/;
        var clean1 = getWord.value.replace(regex1, "****");


        getWord.value = clean1;
        if(//the condition I want to know){
//ifi it is a bad word then show div tag
     $("#wordTraker").slideToggle(300);
    }


        }
        </script>
```

Comment: if you need replace all badwords in comment, append `g` modifier to regexp:
`var regex1 = /(dam|hell)/g;`

Comment: be careful ... that regex would mess up `"hello I am a damsel in distress"` and turn it into `"****o I am a ****sel in distress"`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just got my asnwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If initial string is not equal to modified then there were a badword(s) in one:

```
var clean1 = getWord.value.replace(regex1, "****");

if (clean1 !== getWord.value) {
    getWord.value = clean1;
    //ifi it is a bad word then show div tag
    $("#wordTraker").slideToggle(300);
}
```

Comment: Ohh thank you soo much.. This works perfectly.. Thank you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Before changing the value of `getWord.value` to `clean`, you can check if both are same or not, if they are same then there were no bad words.

Or you can use `match()` to check if there are any bad words or not. If it return `null` then there are no words. However if you do not need the words that are replaced than it will not be very useful.

As mentioned in the comments, your regular expression can give incorrect results, you should check for word boundaries as well. Something like this would be better,

```
/\W+(damn/Hell)\W+/gi
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.. I just got my asnwer